# Solving for Critical Points in Maxima

Tags: math, maxima

I'm trying to solve for the x-coordinates of the critical points of the function A(b) in WxMaxima (the GUI for Maxima), but it refuses to give a numerical solution. When I take the derivative, it leaves terms like d/db(1/2 * x) inside instead of evaluating them. How do I get Maxima to solve for all x-coordinates where the derivative of A(x) is equal to 0? Here is a minimal (pun intended) example of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: Did you mean to write `A_prime(b) := diff(A(b), b);` ? (I.e. to define a function named `A_prime`.)

Comment: Yes. That fixed it! Thanks! But how do I get Maxima to "fully" take derivatives? When I take the derivative of a compound function, Maxima leaves d/dx terms inside instead of fully expanding them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Can you give an example?

Comment: Here's an example:

Comment: ```A(b) := (1/2) * (28 * (-b / 2) + 280) * (b + 10);
A_prime(b) := diff(A(b), b);```

Comment: That snippet outputs `A_prime(b) := diff(A(b), b)` instead of actually differentiating A(b).

Comment: A function defined by `:=` quotes (i.e., does not evaluate) its function body; the function body is evaluated only when the function is called. So in your example, the function body `diff(A(b), b)` isn't evaluated. You can evaluate an expression and create a function from it in two different ways: (1) `define(A_prime(b), diff(A(b), b))` , and (b) `A_primeb(b) := ''(diff(A(b), b))`. Note that the second method makes use of quote-quote, i.e. two single quotes `''` which has the effect of evaluating an expression and then pasting it into the rest of the input. `? define` and `? ''` will say more.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.